# Combining UIDatePicker with text or UIPickerView with date?

Tags: ios, uipickerview, uidatepicker

Is it possible to combine dates (I only need days) and some text (see second picker below) in a double picker ?

[image]
[image]

If yes, are the 2 strategies (datepicker with text or picker view with date) possible ?
If the second one is chosen, how to retrieve days in an array in the format "..., Wed August 28, Today, Fri Aug 30, ..." etc ? Ideally, I would like 15 days before today and 1 week after today.